# How to get actual value from object of JsonPatchDocument in C#?

Tags: c#, json, .net, webapi, json-patch

I have one payload like below to update via patch call in webAPI.

```
[
  {
    "value": [
      {
        "Id": "12",
       "name": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "Id": "89",
       "name": "XYZ"
      }
    ],
    "path": "/basepathofemployee",
    "op": "replace"
  }
]
```

And my action method of controller is like and there I want to get the value of Id & name

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateData([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<EmployeeDocument> patchDoc)
{
   // here I want to get value of Id (12, 89) & name (ABC, XYZ)
}
```

I tried to get the value from the path itself like,

```
    var employee = patchDoc.Operations.Where(o => o.path.Equals("/basepathofemployee"));
```

its giving IEnumerable and if I loop through that I am not getting the actual value of id and name.

Can you pls guide me how to get the actual value of id and name?

Answer (score 0):

if it needs patchdocument:

```
if (patchDoc != null)
    {
        var model = CreateModel(); //need to create instance

        patchDoc.ApplyTo(model, ModelState);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        else{
          // model should have valid properties here
        }

        return new ObjectResult(model);
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
```

should also have this decorator on the action:

```
[HttpPatch]
```

if can do without patchdocument:

just create a class:

```
public class Patch{

 public List<Data> value {get;set;}
 public string path {get;set;}
 public string op {get;set;}
}
```

and another Data

```
public class data{

 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string name {get;set;}
}
```

then change signature to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateData([FromBody] Patch patchDoc)
{
   // here I want to get value of Id (12, 89) & name (ABC, XYZ)
   // should be available patchDoc.value[0].Id / patchDoc.value[1].Id

}
```

might need:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateData([FromBody] List<Patch> patchDoc)
{
   // here I want to get value of Id (12, 89) & name (ABC, XYZ)
   // should be available patchDoc[0].value[0].Id / patchDoc[0].value[1].Id

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the operations in the patch document. Its an array. Like this:

```
foreach (var operation in patchDoc.Operations)
{
   var operationValue = operation.value;
}
```